# UiPath Read Checkbox from PDF using GetText

Tags: pdf, uipath

How to read the checkbox value from PDF (the pdf is not an image):

[image]

Note: I don’t want to use OCR (Find image) because it will be time consuming.

Comment: I think there is no option without OCR concerning reading PDFs. Why not OCR?

Comment: Because there are a lot of checkboxes, so it will be time consuming to search for all those images

Comment: May I know, how the checkbox appears while doing read pdf text?

Comment: The checkbox is not appearing at all. The read pdf text activity is failing to extract it.

Comment: Try using Anchors. Indicate the checkbox with ocr and get the text next to it with get text.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a clean PDF, and if you are able to identify elements then try using **Get Attribute** activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Digitize activity in the IntelligentOCR package. It detects checkboxes and replaces them with two unicode characters you can specifically search for: \u2610 for unchecked and \u2612 for checked.

That activity can look for several kinds of checkboxes and it might just detect yours as well.